# Webview fastest way to reopen

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview activity that shows my interfaces, but I have to call another activity (non webview).

After the other activity has finished I have to go back to the webview one, but it takes too long to open as it recreates the activity in a intent.

Is there a way to keep the webview activity in the background and just reopen it once the other activity has finished? Any suggestions to make the webview at least load faster?

Comment: How are you going back?  If you're just calling finish, that's what it does (unless the OS decides to garbage collect you for resources).

Comment: I'm creating an intent for the other activity and calling finish in the webview one. same thing when going back. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: No need to create the intent.  Finish returns you to the previous Activity.

Comment: The problem is that I need to pass back a result of the other activity back to the webview one. Can I do it without a intent?

Comment: That's built into the system.  From your webview activity, call startActivityForResult.  From your second activity, set the result before finishing.  Then in your first activity, implement onActivityResult.   If you're already doing this (can't tell from your description), then your problem isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Then you're using `startActivityForResult()`, plus `setResult()` before `finish()` in the second activity. That's the correct way to do it.

Comment: I am using putExtra on the intent. Could I store it in the hard drive maybe and catch it when reopen the webview one?

Comment: Got it, implementing....

Comment: There's no need. As @GabeSechan said, OS should keep the WebView in memory, even in that case.

Comment: Worked, thanks a million.